# How do I organize this data so that each ID has one row, and each Action has one column for Daily Contacts in R?

Tags: r, variables, multiple-columns, rows, categorical-data

My dataset is:

| ID | Action | Daily_Contact |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 760 | Email | 5 |
| 760 | Text | 4 |
| 760 | Phone call | 7 |
| 430 | Phone call | 2 |
| 430 | Email | 9 |
| 430 | Text | 8 |

and I want it to look like this,

| ID | Email | Text | PhoneCall |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 760 | 5 | 4 | 7 |
| 430 | 9 | 8 | 2 |

Comment: Okay, what's stopping you?

Answer (score 1):

Next time, please copy and paste the output of dput(df) so it is easier to replicate. Here is a tidyverse solution.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(760,760,760,430,430,430),
                 action=c("email","text","phone","phone","email","text"),
                 daily_contact=c(5,4,7,2,9,8))


df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = action, values_from = daily_contact)
```

EDIT:
TarJae's comment is correct. It works for me too.

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = action, values_from = daily_contact)
```

Comment: You do not need `group_by`: `pivot_wider(df, names_from = action, values_from = daily_contact)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html)

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id, action, Daily_Contact)

dcast(dt, id ~ action, value.var = "Daily_Contact")

##    id Email Phone call Text
## 1: 430     9          2    8
## 2: 760     5          7    4
```